# Integral Representation of Continuous Monotonous Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Edited:** For absolutely continuous functions $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, we know from the fundamental theorem of calculus that
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \; dt + F(a)$$
for some almost everywhere continuous function $f$ (the derivative of $F$).

My question is the following: Is there a similar result for monotonously increasing continuous functions $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can get a measure on R, defined as $\mu(a,b)=F(b)-F(a)$, such that the $\int_a^b d\mu  = F(b)-F(a)$. We can try to apply Radon-Nykodym theorem: seems like if the Lebesgue measure of A is zero, then $\mu(A)=0$. If you had this condition (absolute continuity), you could find such an integral representation!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement itself is false. There exist strictly  monotone continuous functions $F$ such that $F'=0$ almost everywhere which implies that FTC is not valid.

FTC holds iff $F$ is absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The class for which this is true ($f$ can be written as the integral of it's derivative) is the class of absolutely continuous (AC) functions. IIRC you should find this result in one of Rudin's book.

AC is a proper subset of the class of BV (bounded variation) functions, and a function is of bounded variation iff it is the sum of two monotonic functions. So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: According to your statement, if $F$ was additionally bounded, then it should be of bounded variation.

Comment: @dawo Which $F$ are you talking about? Anyway, if a monotonic function is  bounded it is, of course, of bounded variation. The total variaion of a  monotonic $F$ on $[a,b]$ is just, up to sign, $F(b)- F(a)$